# How do I add link to an element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, django, scheduler

So instead of directly using  tag in each element, is there a way to add the tag dynamically?
What I'm trying to do is that first I have a calendar, and when a user clicks a particular date on the calendar, the user can see what happened in that date at a separate page. 
The thing is that I'm using `django-scheduler` library, so the calendar is pre-desiged, meaning I cannot directly make changes to the code. All I have in my template is `{% calendar %}`. So I figured I'd have to control using JavaScript.

Here's what I see in the 'source' of the page:

```
...
<div class="content" data-date="2020-05-27"></div>
<div class="content" data-date="2020-05-28"></div>
<div class="content" data-date="2020-05-29"></div>
...
```

For each `data-date`, I want to add link which looks like : www.some-webpage.com/2020-05-27 

Is it ever possible to do this with JavaScript? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the function below in the `onClick` of the button.
 Here I am using `document.querySelectorAll` to select all elements with `data-date` attribute and then looping over each element to form an `a` tag with link based on the `data-date` attribute.

```js
function addDateLink() {
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-date]').forEach(div => {
        const date = div.getAttribute('data-date')
        div.innerHTML = `<a href="www.some-webpage.com/${date}">${date}</a>`
    })
}
```

```html
<div class="content" data-date="2020-05-27"></div>
<div class="content" data-date="2020-05-28"></div>
<div class="content" data-date="2020-05-29"></div>

<input type="button" value="Display Link" onclick="addDateLink()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I use onClick function then?

Answer (score 0):

you can use map-function for every  and add a link